# BASH | sort files to sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

In my current DIR i have x number of files with different timestamps ex:

```
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Jan  1  2006 file_JAN2006
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Mar  1  2006 file_MAR2006
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Jan  1  2011 file_JAN2011
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Mar  1  2011 file_MAR2011
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Apr  1  2011 file_APR2011
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Jun  1  2011 file_JUN2011
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Nov  1  2015 file_NOV2015
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Dec  1  2015 file_DEC2015
    -rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users    0 Oct  1  2016 file_OCT2016
```

I have created script below that will create subDir for multiple years and inside that yearsDIR, needs to have list of months.

```
mkdir -p {2006..2016}/{Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec}

2006:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2007:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2008:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2009:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2010:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2011:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2012:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2013:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2014:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2015:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept

2016:
Apr  Aug  Dec  Feb  Jan  Jul  Jun  Mar  May  Nov  Oct  Sept
```

How can I sort the months from Jan-Dec? and sort the files listed above into subdirectories according to Years and calendar months.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're seeing them "sorted" by ls, check the ls manpage if you want to see the available sort orders.

Comment: As a side note, check ISO8601 for dates, and you'll discover many benefits not only when programming. I've both trees like year/month/day (always numeric), as files named yyyymmdd. They will sort naturally as numbers or strings and you'll know which one is older at first sight

Comment: The alphabetic order is A-B-C-D-E, not J-F-M-A-M. If you wanted them sorted in month order, then use month numbers such as 01 for January, 02 for February, 03 for March...10 for October, 11 for November, 12 for December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem is one of not actually *"sorting"* per-se, but one of *"moving"* each file (e.g. `file_JAN2006`) into an associate directory based on the year & month (e.g. `2006/Jan`), then your problem is not that difficult (especially with bash as you have tagged your question)

For example, given your list of files in a directory:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_APR2011
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_DEC2015
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_JAN2006
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_JAN2011
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_JUN2011
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_MAR2006
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_MAR2011
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_NOV2015
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Sep 26 14:50 file_OCT2016
```

You can move the files into the directory structure you have specified with a short script as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r fn; do                    ## loop over each filename
    m="${fn:5:3}"                       ## get month (string indexes)
    m="${m,,}"                          ## convert to lowercase
    m="${m^}"                           ## 1st char to uppercase
    y="${fn:8}"                         ## get year (string indexes)
    test -d "$y/$m" || mkdir -p "$y/$m" ## create dir for file
    printf "mv %s %s\n" "$fn" "$y/$m"   ## print what is being done
    mv "$fn" "$y/$m"                    ## move file into new dir
done
```

Piping the filenames to the script or using *process substitution* to produce a list of filenames will move the files to their new home, e.g.

```
$ bash ../parse.sh < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file_*" -printf "%f\n")
```

Of course if you just wanted to copy/paste the commands into a terminal and do without the script, you could replace `while read -r fn; do` with `for fn i *; do`. For example the following does the same thing:

```
for fn in file_*; do                    ## loop over each filename
    m="${fn:5:3}"                       ## get month (string indexes)
    m="${m,,}"                          ## convert to lowercase
    m="${m^}"                           ## 1st char to uppercase
    y="${fn:8}"                         ## get year (string indexes)
    test -d "$y/$m" || mkdir -p "$y/$m" ## create dir for file
    printf "mv %s %s\n" "$fn" "$y/$m"   ## print what is being done
    mv "$fn" "$y/$m"                    ## move file into new dir
done
```

Either way, the resulting file/directory structure would be:

```
$ tree
.
├── 2006
│   ├── Jan
│   │   └── file_JAN2006
│   └── Mar
│       └── file_MAR2006
├── 2011
│   ├── Apr
│   │   └── file_APR2011
│   ├── Jan
│   │   └── file_JAN2011
│   ├── Jun
│   │   └── file_JUN2011
│   └── Mar
│       └── file_MAR2011
├── 2015
│   ├── Dec
│   │   └── file_DEC2015
│   └── Nov
│       └── file_NOV2015
└── 2016
    └── Oct
        └── file_OCT2016

13 directories, 9 files
```

If I misunderstood your question, or if you have any further questions, let me know.

Comment: Hi David, may I also ask some assistance on this one (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394826/bash-path-display-on-a-report?noredirect=1#comment704554_394826)
thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, see my comment to your question on unix.stackexchange.